# Reference workbook by path and name error: Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I get the "Subscript out of range" error from the line below:

```
Set WBset =  Workbooks("FilePath\PK18 - Unformatted.xls").Worksheets("PK18 - Unformatted")
```

I checked the sheet name and the filename and they are correct. The sheet exists.

Comment: @JvdV i've tried it both open and closed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming WBset is a Workbook Object, you need to remove the file path from the command so it looks like the following.  The file needs to be open as Workbooks is a collection of the Workbook objects open.

```
Set WBset =  Workbooks("PK18 - Unformatted.xls").Worksheets("PK18 - Unformatted")
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong workbook name, should be the name not the path